# Python pylint "warning error uncreachable code"

Tags: python, pylint

I have this method in my game and I'm getting the "*Unreachable code*" warning from *pylint*.

```
def _check_buttons(self, mouse_pos):
    """Check for buttons being clicked and act accordingly."""
    buttons = {
    self.play_button.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
        lambda: (self._reset_game(),
                 setattr(self, 'show_difficulty', False),
                 setattr(self, 'show_high_scores', False),
                 setattr(self, 'show_game_modes', False)),
    self.quit_button.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
        lambda: (pygame.quit(), sys.exit()),
    self.menu_button.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
        self.run_menu,
    self.high_scores.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
        lambda: setattr(self, 'show_high_scores', not self.show_high_scores),
    self.game_modes.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
        lambda: setattr(self, 'show_game_modes', not self.show_game_modes),
    self.endless_button.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
        lambda: (setattr(self.settings, 'endless', not self.settings.endless),
                 setattr(self, 'show_game_modes', False)),
    self.easy.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
        lambda: (setattr(self.settings, 'speedup_scale', 0.3),
                 setattr(self, 'show_difficulty', False)),
    self.medium.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
        lambda: (setattr(self.settings, 'speedup_scale', 0.5),
                 setattr(self, 'show_difficulty', False)),
    self.hard.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
        lambda: (setattr(self.settings, 'speedup_scale', 0.7),
                 setattr(self, 'show_difficulty', False)),
    self.difficulty.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
        lambda: setattr(self, 'show_difficulty', not self.show_difficulty)
    }

    for button_clicked, action in buttons.items():
        if button_clicked and not self.stats.game_active:
            action()
```

The warning is in the for loop at the end, I thought it was because button_clicked is always True and I tried to swap it to: if not self.stats.game_active and button_clicked, but the warning is still there. Why?

Comment: What is `self.stats.game_active`? Is it always `True`?

Comment: It's not always True, I tried to remove the check for self.stats.game_active but it's the same. I mean, even if i'm adding a random print('123') after the creation of the dict, it says that it's unreachable. The thing is that the buttons are all working well, even with that warning.

Comment: Ok, so if your code works fine, then it must be a false positive from `pylint`. I always find that working tests trump static analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I tried to simplify my code, I solved the problem by doing this:

```
def create_button_actions_dict(self):
    """Create a dictionary mapping buttons to their corresponding actions."""
    return {
        self.play_button: self.handle_play_button,
        self.quit_button: self.handle_quit_button,
        self.menu_button: self.run_menu,
        self.high_scores: self.handle_high_scores_button,
        self.game_modes: self.handle_game_modes_button,
        self.endless_button: self.handle_endless_button,
        self.easy: self.handle_difficulty_button(0.3),
        self.medium: self.handle_difficulty_button(0.5),
        self.hard: self.handle_difficulty_button(0.7),
        self.difficulty: self.handle_difficulty_toggle
    }

def _check_buttons(self, mouse_pos):
    """Check for buttons being clicked and act accordingly."""
    button_actions = self.create_button_actions_dict()
    for button in button_actions:
        if button.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos) and not self.stats.game_active:
            button_actions[button]()

def handle_play_button(self):
    """Reset game and hide all buttons"""
    self._reset_game()
    self.show_difficulty = False
    self.show_high_scores = False
    self.show_game_modes = False

def handle_quit_button(self):
    """Quit game"""
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

def handle_high_scores_button(self):
    """Toggle the visibility of the high score"""
    self.show_high_scores = not self.show_high_scores

def handle_game_modes_button(self):
    """Toggle the visibility of the game modes"""
    self.show_game_modes = not self.show_game_modes

def handle_endless_button(self):
    """Toggle the game endless game mode setting and hide game mode buttons"""
    self.settings.endless = not self.settings.endless
    self.show_game_modes = False

def handle_difficulty_button(self, speedup_scale):
    """Set the game difficulty (speed-up scale)"""
    def handle():
        self.settings.speedup_scale = speedup_scale
        self.show_difficulty = False
    return handle

def handle_difficulty_toggle(self):
    """Toggle visibility of the difficulty buttons"""
    self.show_difficulty = not self.show_difficulty
```